# Subinterfaces at Cisco routers

Tags: router, cisco-ios

What is behavior of subinterface on cisco router that has configured

```
#encapsulation dot1q vlan_id
```

but has no IP address configured? Will it work as L2 interface? Or will not work at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work as a L2 interface only if you have configured bridging on the router.